# Открытие главной формы после авторизации на второй

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 2 формы: 1 - главная, 2 - окно авторизации.
Первая форма по умолчанию скрыта и должна открываться только после авторизации. Проблема в том, что когда закрываешь вторую форму и возвращаешься к первой, она открывается по новой, и выполняет все, что находится в Form1_Load. Соответственно, мне это не нужно. Закрытие второй формы и открытие первой:

```
Hide();
Form f1 = new Form1();
```

Код авторизации:

```
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
string pass = textBox2.Text;
byte[] checkSum = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass));
string result = BitConverter.ToString(checkSum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
result = result.ToLower();
//БД
string myConnectionString = "Database=" + ParamDB + ";Data Source=" + ParamServer + ";User Id=" + ParamUser + ";Password=" + ParamPass + "";
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
string user_pass = "";
try
{
   string Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + textBox1.Text + "';";
   MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConnection);
   MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
   myConnection.Open();
   MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
   while (MyReader2.Read())
     {
         user_pass = MyReader2.GetString(3);
     }
   myConnection.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка");
     }
   if (result == user_pass)
     {
         Form1 form = new Form1();
         this.Close();
         form.ShowDialog();
      }
   else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Введен неверный логин или пароль");
      }
```

Что посоветуете?

Comment: WinForms? WPF?...

Comment: Windows Forms..

Comment: Советую использовать решение Oleg GranRCM. Все остальные решения - костыли

Answer (score 1):

Можно в форме авторизации добавить свойство `public bool IsAuthenticated { get; private set; }`.

Тогда в `Program.cs` пишем:

```
LogonForm logonForm = new LogonForm(); 

// Вызов формы авторизации 
Application.Run(logonForm);

// Проверка авторизации пользователя 
if (logonForm.IsAuthenticated) 
{ 
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

Comment: Если не трудно, поясните пожалуйста что куда тут, ибо у меня все красным подчеркнуто

Comment: @g431k `LogonForm` - это класс Вашей формы авторизации, `MainForm` - класс Вашей главной формы. Данный код помещается в файл `Program.cs`. В классе `LogonForm` Вы добавляете свойство `public bool IsAuthenticated { get; private set; }` и устанавливаете его в зависимости от успешности авторизации.

Comment: @g431k, разобрались?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте делать так:

1. Создаёте форму логина, в которой делаете все необходимые проверки, и если всё хорошо, то закрываете ее с `DialogResult == OK`.
2. Если форма логина была вызвана и всё прошло успешно, то продолжаем работу дальше, в противном случае просто выходим.

Примерно так это может выглядеть в вашем `Program.cs`:

```
    ....
    static void Main()
    {
        const int LOGIN_ERROR = -1; //Можете задать иной код для ошибки логина
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // Создаём форму логина
        var loginForm = new LoginForm();
        // Показываем её и ждём результата, с которым форма будет закрыта в в зависимости от которого
        // будем решать, что делать дальше:
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Если форма закрылась не по кнопке OK, то выходим
            Environment.Exit(LOGIN_ERROR);
        }

        //Здесь можно проверить корректность авторизации, и если она не верна, то выйти из приложения.

        //Запускаем наше приложение и главную форму.
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

Разумеется, могут быть и другие варианты реализации. Я бы, например, сначала вызывал бы форму для логина, ждал бы пока пользователь нажемёт в ней копку ОК или Отмена (нужно создать эти кнопки на форме логина и задать каждой из них свойство `DialogResult` как `OK` и `Cancel` соответственно). Дальше делал бы все проверки корректности логина только если пользователь нажал ОК, а если он нажал отмену, значит он передумал логинится и наше приложение ему не нужно, потому сразу выходим, даже не создавая и не запуская нашу главную форму.

---

Конкретно для вашего случая можно сделать так:

1. В классе вашей главной формы добавьте следующий метод:

   ```
   public bool IsLoginSuccessed()
   {
       //Если true - будем пытаться попробовать залогинится еще раз
       bool tryToLogin = true;
       //Если true - логин/пароль верны и приняты
       bool loginAccepted = false;

       while (tryToLogin)
       {
           var lf = new LoginForm();
           var dr = lf.ShowDialog();
           if (dr != DialogResult.OK)
           {
               //Нажата отмена или закрыто окно - больше не пытаемся логинится
               tryToLogin = false;
               //Логин не принят
               loginAccepted = false;
           }

           //Здесь ваш код для подключения к БД и получения данных из неё:
           MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
           string pass = textBox2.Text;
           byte[] checkSum = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass));
           string result = BitConverter.ToString(checkSum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
           result = result.ToLower();
           //БД
           string myConnectionString = "Database=" + ParamDB + ";Data Source=" + ParamServer + ";User Id=" + ParamUser + ";Password=" + ParamPass + "";
           MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
           string user_pass = "";
           try
           {
              string Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + textBox1.Text + "';";
              MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConnection);
              MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
              myConnection.Open();
              MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
              while (MyReader2.Read())
              {
                  user_pass = MyReader2.GetString(3);
              }
              myConnection.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка");
           }

           //Осуществляем проверку логина и пароля только если мы пытаемся логинится
           if (tryToLogin)
               if (result != user_pass)
               {
                   //Ошибочный логин/пароль
                   MessageBox.Show("Введен неверный логин или пароль");
               }
               else
               {
                   //Авторизация успешна!
                   loginAccepted = true;
                   //Значит не пытаемся авторизоваться еще раз:
                   tryToLogin = false;

                   MessageBox.Show("Авторизация успешна!");
               }
       }
       return loginAccepted;
   }
   ```
2. Теперь в нужный момент вызвать авторизацию можно так:

   `bool IsUserLogged = IsLoginSuccessed();`

При этом можно вызывать этот метод из главной формы, если сама она невидима (скрыта), например, еще до запуска самого приложения. В итоге приложение не запустится, если пользователь не авторизован:

```
    ....
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var mf = new MainForm();
        if (mf.IsLoginSuccessed())
            Application.Run(mf);
    }
    ....
```

Всё.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте на форме авторизации, когда необходимо закрыть авторизацию и открыть главную  так :

```
 Form1 form= new Form1();
 this.Close();
 form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: К сожалению, также открывает новую

Comment: Причем открывает новую, раньше чем закроется форма авторизации. Эта строка `Form1 form= new Form1();` у меня выполняется сама по себе, т.е. не требует `.Show();`

Comment: Покажите код формы авторизации.

Comment: Если открывает новую форму раньше чем закроется старая, то возможно нужно поменять местами `.Hide();`-формы авторизации и `.Show();` - главной формы

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:
На первой форме:

```
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
 this.Hide();
 if(form2.ShowDialog()!=DialogResult.OK)
       this.Close();
 else
 {
       this.Show();
 }
```

На второй (в случае успешной авторизации):

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

и просто (в случае провала):

```
this.Close();
```

Первая форма скрывает себя, ждет когда отработает вторая, и когда она закрывается, вновь себя показывает. Если создавать(любым методом), первую форму из второй - это будет НОВАЯ форма).

Вариант 2: Изменить конструктор второй формы, и прокинуть на него ссылку на первую форму. А уже на полученной ссылке вызывать `Show()`. Но это чуть сложнее.

Comment: Почти идеально, но есть одно НО... Авторизации может не быть вовсе, она нужна для доступа к настройкам программы. И главная форма скрывается при запуске программы.. +возможно что окно авторизации будет просто закрыто и тогда, откроется 1 форма без авторизации

Comment: Ну с первым на мой взгляд проблем нету. Не обязательно это код вешать в `Form.Load()`. Можно повесить его на код открытия настроек программы. Со вторым веселее, но тут либо делать флаг авторизации. Либо возвращаемое значение (которое потом проверять на первой форме (если форма вернула -1, закрыться).

Comment: Но в целом работа с конструктором, чуть сложнее для понимания, но удобнее для работы. Если требуется, могу написать и этот вариант в более расширенном)

Comment: Нно, тогда после `this.Close();` второй формы ничего не происходит

Comment: В каком случае?) все 4 команды надо запихивать в кнопку.

Я поправил свой ответ с более расширенным вариантом. Данный код учитывает все. И запихивать вот кусок кода с первой формы надо именно туда, где надо показать форму авторизации (полностью)